# Dropdown Menu not displayed in internet explorer 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu that refuses to work in IE6/7

Should look like this (print in Firefox)

[image]

The CSS

```
ul.menuSM li span {
    width: 17px;
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
        /*THIS IMAGE REPRESENTS THE RED ARROW NEXT TO THE LOGO*/
    background:url(../nImg/subnav_btn.gif) no-repeat center top;
    margin-left: 2px;
    text-indent:3000px;
}
ul.menuSM li span.subhover {
    background-position: center bottom;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/*THE DROP DOWN MENU*/
ul.menuSM li ul.submenuSM {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
        /*TRIED ALSO with:  *position:fixed;  to hack ie6/7 but neither..*/
    left: 0;
    top: 32px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    z-index: 1405;
}
```

The source HTML (please note that there's no `<span>` here yet

```
**<ul class="menuSM">
                                <li> <a href="#"><img src="../../nImg/logoMeliaGold.png" alt="" /></a>
                                    <ul class="submenuSM">
                                        <li><a href="http://es.solmelia.com/buscar/busqueda-avanzada.htm">Reservas</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://es.solmelia.com/hoteles/ofertas.htm">Ofertas</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://es.solmelia.com/hoteles">Destinos</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://es.solmelia.com/hoteles/msm">Eventos y reuniones</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://es.solmelia.com/nFamilias/jsp/C_Home.jsp">Familias</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>**
```

Some JS That appends the  because i can't edit the HTML source :(

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("ul.submenuSM").parent().append("<span></span>"); 
    /* And this shows the dropdow but i tried also setting in the CSS display:block so i don't depend of javaScript and still can't see the dropdown */ 
    $("ul.menuSM li span").click(function() {       
        $(this).parent().find("ul.submenuSM").slideDown('fast').show();  
        $(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function(){  
            $(this).parent().find("ul.submenuSM").slideUp('slow'); 
        }); 
        }).hover(function() { 
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); 
        }, function(){  
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

The Final HTML

```
<ul class="menuSM">
                            <li> <a href="#"><img src="../../nImg/logoMeliaGold.png" alt="" /></a><span></span>
                                <ul class="submenuSM">
                                    <li><a href="http://es.solmelia.com/buscar/busqueda-avanzada.htm">Reservas</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://es.solmelia.com/hoteles/ofertas.htm">Ofertas</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://es.solmelia.com/hoteles">Destinos</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://es.solmelia.com/hoteles/msm">Eventos y reuniones</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="http://es.solmelia.com/nFamilias/jsp/C_Home.jsp">Familias</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Some CSS that loads the arrow

Any idea what i'm missing?

PS: it works in IE8

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```
*+html div{
    z-index:1400;
}
*+html .conFranjaHomeGold{
    z-index:1 !important;
}
```

It was another module's problem..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple fix but, have you declared the DOCTYPE?

Comment: If it works in IE8 (as stated at the end of the question), this (for once!) can't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a lot of arbitrary and hard-coded numbers in your code, perhaps you could try to reverse engineer this menu of mine that is tried and tested in IE7+ and all other browsers: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

It can be made to work in IE6 with http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html

H

Comment: well, thanks a lot but it whas a z-index problem :D finaly found it :D